# Wordpress about me page, replicate when installing new theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

What I want to do is install a template, and that template automaticly create a page, like the abotu me page is created when you first install wordpress. how can I do this? How do you run an SQL statment when you install a new theme? since pages are stored in the database I could just upload teh page this way when installing the theme but I have no ideia how.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My above answer is for adding posts. The below answer is to add a page (it adds the page on theme activation):

```
if (isset($_GET['activated']) && is_admin()){
    $new_page_title = 'This is the page title';
    $new_page_content = 'This is the page content';
    $new_page_template = ''; //ex. template-custom.php. Leave blank if you don't want a custom page template.
    //don't change the code bellow, unless you know what you're doing
    $page_check = get_page_by_title($new_page_title);
    $new_page = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_title' => $new_page_title,
        'post_content' => $new_page_content,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
    );
    if(!isset($page_check->ID)){
        $new_page_id = wp_insert_post($new_page);
        if(!empty($new_page_template)){
            update_post_meta($new_page_id, '_wp_page_template', $new_page_template);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: taken from: http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/create-page-on-theme-activation/

Answer (score 1):

JCHASE, I agree with wp_insert_post part, the only thing that I would suggest is using an action hook instead of $_GET.  Using add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_initiation_function') would be a better option

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it for posts:

```
global $user_ID;
$new_post = array(
'post_title' => 'My New Post',
'post_content' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
'post_author' => $user_ID,
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_category' => array(0)
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

See below for pages. See [this page](http://www.webmaster-source.com/2010/02/09/programmatically-creating-posts-in-wordpress/) for the reference.